# Insert PDF dynamic stamp as a readonly object via JS

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

Is it possible to make a stamp readonly as soon as it is placed?

I know how to do it with a function later, such as

```
this.selectedAnnots[0].readOnly = true;
```

But it would be more convenient to make it read only as soon as its placed on the dynamic stamp javascript.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that the annotation doesn't exist until it's placed but your code runs before that. You'd need run your code after a delay. In the example below, "event.source.source" is the PDF document.
You can probably do it using...

```
app.setTimeOut("event.source.source.selectedAnnots[0].readOnly = true",500);
```

I haven't actually tested this.